# Silverlight TreeViewItem, Binding to IsSelected, how to?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, treeview, mvvm-light

In reading a post about TreeView and binding to a view model (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx), it seems that binding a TreeViewItem IsSelected property is possible.  However, I have the following code which always fails on Initialize() because it's trying to set a read-only property?

```
       <sdk:TreeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewStyle}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding tvData}" > 
            <sdk:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle> 
                <Style TargetType="sdk:TreeViewItem"> 
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" /> 
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" /> 
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" /> 
                </Style> 
            </sdk:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle> 
            <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate> 
                <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"> 
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" FontWeight="{Binding ItemFontWeight}"/> 
                    </StackPanel>                         
                </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>                     
            </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign a binding via a `Setter` in a `Style`.  Effectively what you are doing there is attempting to set a binding on the `Setter.Value` property.  Xaml doesn't infer that you mean to set a binding on the target property.  In turn the `Setter` just assumes you are trying to set a value directly to `IsSelected` which it knows is read only hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend this technique for getting around the problem:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/05/07/one-more-platform-difference-more-or-less-tamed-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better.aspx

EDIT: 
I should mention that I have not tried the technique for this exact scenario (binding the IsSelected property of a TreeViewItem), but I have used it on numerous other occasions, and so far it has worked flawlessly.